# How to make project inherit it's settings from another project in VS2013?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

I want to create a Native C++ project which inherits it's settings from another Native C++ project within the same solution, so if I were to change the settings from the base project, it will be reflected in the derived project.

Is this possible?  I use the word inherit because I see that in the project settings, though I'm not sure where it's inheriting from.

Answer (score 1):

Project settings sharing is done via Property Sheets.

Go to View -> Property Manager, right-click on one of your projects and select "Add New Project Property Sheet...". Choose some common place for it, that is easily accessible by all other projects (somewhere near solution file will do).

Double-click on that new property sheet and set whatever options you want your projects to share. Now you can add this property sheet to any other project via "Add Existing Property Sheet...".

Comment: This is interesting, however, I can't get it to work with my include directories.  E.g. I create a property sheet from one project, assign that property sheet to another.  A source and header file from the project that I just extracted the property sheet from is added to the new project.  I build and it fails because that source file includes a file that is from another include directory that was listed in the first project, but the directory wasn't transferred to the new project.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get it: WHY the source and header files from one project are added to the new project? Files are not listed in the property sheet, are they? Could you please illustrate with the example what are you trying to share between your projects?

Answer (score 0):

It is inheriting from the solution. If you have both projects in the same solution then you can specify some of settings in the solution and have the projects inherit from the solution. You can then change the a setting in the solution and it be reflected in both projects.

Comment: This is what intuitively makes sense, but I already checked this.  There are no C++/Linker settings in the solution by right clicking on solution and select properties, most likely as there can be other project types such as VB, C# and others.  Is there a way to inherit from a particular project?