# Two projects with only some different files AND keep most parts in sync with each other

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, projects-and-solutions

I have a single project with 300 `.h`/`.cpp`.

**Here are my project characteristic :-**

- My own `.h`/`.cpp` files are divided into many different ***filter*** in Solution Explorer.
- Most `#include` tends to be *upward* along the filter, i.e. lower files tends to `#include` some upper files, but not vice-versa.

  For example, some `utility` tends to include some files in `core`. (see the structure below)
- All of my `.h`/`.cpp` are currently in the same (Window-Explorer) system ***folder***.

### Current project structure

Here is a simplified version of the project.

`#1` is the existing code, while `#2` is just a future plan.

```
core 
   - math library (i.e. it is in a sub-filter)
   - fast interpolation
   - etc
utility   $
   - #1
       - B1.h B1.cpp
       - B2.h B2.cpp 
   - (#2)             <--- currently not exist
       - B1.h B1.cpp  (same name but different content)
       - B3.h B3.cpp  (different name)
my graphic code / my physic code
game 
   - game engine
   - game library
   - game content     $
      - #1
          - C1.h C1.cpp
          - C2.h C2.cpp 
      - (#2)             <--- currently not exist
          - C1.h C1.cpp  (same name but different content)
          - C3.h C3.cpp  (different name)
cover loop      
   - main.cpp
```

### Objective

I plan to code all `#2` files, but not sure how to configure my project, and where to keep the `#2` files.

I will want to swap in/out all files in the filter `#1` vs `#2` inside `$` (`utility` and `game content`) of the project easily.

More specifically, I want something *similar* as :-

- I press a button **X** -> the project will compile/run as if it has all files in `#1` but no `#2` files.
- I press a button **Y** -> the project will compile/run as if it has all files in `#2` but no `#1` files.
- If I **change code** or **add a new file** inside the filter that is not in `$`, the file will impact both *configuration* **X** and **Y**.
- If I **add a new file** inside `$`, I will have a way to indicate which *configuration* (**X**/**Y**) it should reside in.
- Context clue (`ctrl+space`, intellisense) will be smart as if it considers only appropriate file in the current configuration (**X**/**Y**).

### **Question**

How should I configure my project(s)?
Is there any  feature in Visual Studio that do something *similar* to this?
I don't think just creating 2 projects can satisfy the above requirement.

I thought about using **repository** to swap, but it seems to be an inappropriate tool for this task.

A similar question only talk about [inherit project setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33267001/how-to-make-project-inherit-its-settings-from-another-project-in-vs2013).

Comment: Does it need to be all in just one project? You could separate the different versions of, say, B2(.h/.cpp) in two libraries, and have two targets in your main project, each with the include and lib path for each library respectively.

Comment: @Fabio Ceconello   No, it doesn't.  I don't mind create 2 projects. Does your approach require some change in code content?   It is tedious?  Note that `#1` and `#2` have a lot of files.  Will it be still practical to create "lib"?  .... Do I need to add some ugly code like `#define DECLDIR __declspec(dllexport)` into a lot of my files manually?

Comment: Not only it's practical, it'll be easier to manage this way, but how many is "a lot"?. About dllexport, no, I'm talking about creating a static library, not a DLL. So you'll still have just one final executable and no changes are needed in the source files themselves.

Comment: @Fabio Ceconello  Wow, that looks cool.  I didn't know that is possible.  ...... About "a lot" : Let's say my project is divided into 5 section from top-to-bottom in Solution Explorer.  It will be `filter1`, `filter2 with $`, `filter3`,  `filter4 with $`  and `filter5`.  The amount of pairs `.h/.cpp` are around `100 10 200 100 20` respectively.    ...... I will read some static library tutorial now e.g. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235627.aspx#BKMK_CreateLibProject.